# how to correctly format this glyphicon button with input field using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a search button inside an input field and i already did it.Here is my current output.

[image]

i used `class="btn btn-xs btn-danger` to to have a button with red background and white color symbol just like bootstrap danger buttons.But as you can see that its not doing it.

here is my code:

```
<div class="input-group">                      
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeid"  placeholder="Enter ID"> 
   <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" id="search" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search "  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
   </button>   
   </span>                                 
</div>
```

so how can i do it.thanks

Comment: The button is red as you've made it within the CSS. The offending element is the `span` tag inside it. Use Firebug or Developer Tools to inspect the code and you can see what CSS is being applied to what.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `<button>`tag you have two other tags, each with their own CSS. So you'll need to set the `background-color` to be red, probably on the `<i>` tag. The tip above to use developer tools is a good idea as that will show you a lot quicker where the `background-color` is being set.

Comment: Thanks @stingland  .i did `style="background-color:red;"`.backgrounds get red.But its not restoring all color property of boot strap button of type  `btn-danger`.Thanks

Comment: Your welcome. I take it that has solved the issue then? Also instead of putting the style in the html create a css class (maybe call it red) and put it add it to the element. Helps keep your code a little cleaner and you can also reuse it.